# Classifying the Data

Tags: matlab

So, I have to build this classification 'tree' of 6 levels using tags from the image domain  and the video domain, so that I can classify better. The problem is I don't understand how as this is not really my area of knowledge.

We denote the tag collection and their correlations as N = {ni} and
E = {ei,j |ni, nj ∈ N}, where

e(i,j) = e(i,j . e(i,j)/e(i,j)+ e(i,j)

is the harmonic-mean of the correlations between concept i
and j , normalized such that (sigma)(e(i,j))=(sigma)(e(i,j)YT)=1

My question is how am I to calculate the correlation between two tags, all the correlation examples I have seen so far are for sets of data? Also how do I normalize such that the sum is equal to 1?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may find my answer to [MATLAB Tree Construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082731/matlab-tree-construction) useful. To find this correlation, you can create an array of length N (the number of images/videos in this file), where the kth value is 0 if that image does not have the tag and 1 if it does. The correlation between two arrays like this can be found with

```
corr(tag1, tag2);
```

To normalise - you will have an M-by-M (where M is the number of tags) matrix `e`. Normalise with:

```
normalised_e = e ./ sum(e(:));
```

where `sum(e(:))` is giving you the sum of everything in `e`. You can check if a matrix is normalised because:

```
sum(e(:)) == 1
```