# MATLAB Tree Construction

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Now, I have separate any pair that is in common between the two input files. Find out the  mean between that pair like this : (correlation in first text file)X(correlation in second text file)/ (correlation in first text file)+(correlation in second text file). Again store these in a separate matrix.

Building a tree :
Now, out of all the elements in both the input files, select the 10 most frequent ones. Each of these form the root of a separate K tree.The algorithm goes like this : For the word at the root level, check all its harmonic mean values with the other tags in the matrix that is developed in the previous step. Select the top two highest harmonic means, and put the other word in the tag pair as  the child node of the root.

Can someone please guide me through the MATLAB steps of going through this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so start by putting the data in a useful format; maybe count the number of distinct words, and make an N-by-M matrix of binary values (I'll call this `data1`). Each of the N rows will describe the words associated with a single image. Each of the M columns will descibe the images for which a single word is tagged. Therefore, the value at (N, M) is 0 if tag M is not in image N, and 1 if it is.

From this matrix, to find correlation between all pairs of words, you could do:

```
correlations1 = zeros(M, M);
for i=1:M
  for j=1:M
    correlations1(i, j) = corr(data1(:, i), data1(:, j));
  end
end
```

now the matrix `correlations` tells you the correlation between tags. Do the same for the other text file. You can make a matrix of harmonic means with:

```
h_means = correlations1.*correlations2./(correlations1+correlations2);
```

You can find the 30 most freqent tags by counting the number of 1s in each column of the data matrix. Since we want to find the most common tags in both files, we'll add the data matricies first:

```
[~, tag_ranks] = sort(sum(data1 + data2, 1), 'descending'); %get the indices in sorted order
top_tags = tag_ranks(1:30);
```

For the tree building at the end, you will either want to create a tree class (see [classdef](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/classdef.html)), or store the tree in an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). To find the top two highest harmonic means, you will want to look in the h_means matrix; for a tag m1, we can do:

```
[~, tag_ranks] = sort(h_means(m1, :), 'descending');
top_tag = tag_ranks(1);
second_tag = tag_ranks(2);
```

You will then need to insert these tags into the tree and repeat.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! You have no idea how gratified I feel.Well,everything is clear except the construction of the data1 part..ok, so suppose I have the tags {camel,sand,desert} for image1 and {sand,beach,waves} for image2 and {sand,dust,garbage} for image3 - how will the data1 matrix look?

Comment: You'd need to number each possible tag - for example by producing a single cell array that contains each tag once: {camel, sand, desert, beach, waves, dust, garbage}. Then your matrix would look like [1 1 1 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 1 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]; the rows correspond to images, and each column says whether the corresponding tag is applied to that image.

Comment: Hmm yeah I get it..thanks! Ive got another question  :while performing all these operations, don't we lose sight of the tags(which are words), like my output has to be 30 trees that are labeled with words, how will I know which word is being referred to by a sequence of 0's and 1's? Or wait...do I have to keep track of the column number to keep track of the words?

Comment: If you keep that cell array with each of the tags, then you'll know that the first column of the data matrix is associated with the first tag in the cell array. The same with the correlation matrix. So if you have `all_tags = {camel, sand, desert, beach, waves, dust, garbage}` then you can find the name of, e.g. the largest h_mean tag with `top_tag = tag_ranks(1); tag_name = all_tags{top_tag};`

Comment: Yeah I realized when I executed the program :) It works perfectly, though I think the image tag matrix and the video tag matrix have to have the same dimensions for the h_means statement to work no?

Comment: yes, though I would suggest combining the image and video tags anyway, so that both correlation matrices are the same size - it will just mean that some columns in `data` will be all 0.

Comment: Im getting the same tags over and over, that can't be right. Ive written the last three lines of your code like this :

Comment: for x=1:8    %constructing 8 ktrees
[~, tag_ranks] = sort(h_means(:, top_tags(1,x)), 'descend');    
top_tag = tag_ranks(1);                                           
second_tag = tag_ranks(2);                                         

[~, tag_ranks] = sort(h_means(:, top_tag), 'descend');             first child's children
top_tag1 = tag_ranks(1);
second_tag1 = tag_ranks(2);

[~, tag_ranks] = sort(h_means(:, second_tag), 'descend');         %second child's children.
top_tag2 = tag_ranks(1);
second_tag2= tag_ranks(2);